# Import module from one python install into another

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-import, python-module

I am under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have two python installations. I am actually using them via `pvpython`, but this is likely irrelevant for the present question.
The versions are:

1. Python 2.7.12, installed with `apt-get`, residing in system dirs.
2. Python 2.7.11, residing in `~/apps/ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit`, simply expanded from a tar file. To get the python prompt I run `~/apps/ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/bin/pvpython`.

I mean to use readline from version 1 in version 2 (since it does not have its own, strange as it may be).
To do this:

1. Find where is `readline` in version 1:

   ```
   >>> import readline
   >>> readline.__file__
   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
   ```
2. Use it in version 2, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13466708/2707864). I placed needed stuff in a directory `dir1` which is an element of `sys.path` (I tried with both `/home/santiago/apps/ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/lib/python2.7` and `/home/santiago/apps/ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload`).

   2.1. Get the `.so` file.

   ```
   $ cd dir1
   $ ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
   ```

   2.2. Create `readline.py`

   ```
   $ nano readline.py
   ```

   with contents (as per [ref above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13466708/2707864)):

   ```
   def __bootstrap():
   global __bootstrap, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
   __bootstrap()
   ```

Now when I use version 2 with `~/apps/ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/bin/pvpython`, I still get the error (that I wanted to get rid of)

```
ImportError: No module named readline
```

from an `import` in my `~/.pythonrc`.

**How can I import readline from version 1 into version 2?**

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this.
The key was to link with the name `readline.so` instead of the original name.
The rest was irrelevant.

In 2.1 of the OP:

```
$ cd ~/apps/ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
$ ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so readline.so
```

That is it.
It turns out that `readline.py` with `__bootstrap` (item 2.2) was not needed.