# import python module so file

Tags: python, shared-libraries, python-importlib

I created a python package on a Unix system compiling several fortran function and writing a few python lines as a wrapper.

this module works just fine on that Unix machine.
Since it requires being connected I am trying to make it available on my MAC.

The module contains a .so file that on unix I can import as

```
import _mymodule
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968309/how-to-import-python-module-from-so-file) I managed to read the shared object

```
mymodule = importlib.import_module(__name__,'_mymodule.so')
```

If I run

```
dir(mymodule)
```

> ['**builtins**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**name**', '**package**',
> '**spec**']

which is not the contenct I get if I run from Terminal:

```
 nm -gDC _mymodule.so
```

Now how can I use the functions inside it? or just simply list them?
I can list the function inside it  using

I would like to do something like

```
 data = _mymodule.myfunction(param1,param2)
```

I also tried ctypes

```
lib_mymodule = CDLL('_mymodule.so')
```

with this result

> OSError: dlopen(_mymodule.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
> _mymodule.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C
> 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00

Comment: Did you try `dir(_mymodule)`?

Comment: tried I get ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__'] which is not the content of I get running nm -gDC _mymodule.so from Terminal