# Importing python module from .so file

Tags: python, dll, shared-libraries, importerror, cpython

I am having trouble importing `my_so_file.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` as a python module.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13466708/15452880) helps to some extent, but yields an error `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing my_so_file: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

As [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application) suggests, I made sure that both Windows and Python are 64-bit. They also add opencv binaries path to PATH environment variable, but this does not seem to be relevant to me as I don't deal with opencv. But if I have to add something to PATH, I don't quite understand what it would have to be.

Thank you!

Comment: The obvious problem here is that you have a binary built for linux (.so) and you’re trying to use it on Windows. You need to use  a DLL built with the same code on Windows.

Comment: @tromgy but what if I have only built for linux and no built for windows? Is there any workaround?

Comment: If you have the source you can try building it on Windows. Lacking that  you can use a VM and set up Linux on it. Another possibility to look into is [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)